# How to get a section Name in an Ini file using RegEx

Tags: regex, delphi

I am using this RegEx below to extract the Name of a section in an Ini file.

```
^\s*\[([a-z_][0-9])\]\s*
```

but I cannot get it to find a match even on a simple line like

```
[Compiler]
Path=C:\ProgramFiles (x86)\ProtonIDE\PDS
Database=C:\Program Files (x86)\ProtonIDE
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Alternatively, you could use an INI file parser, like `TMemIniFile` and its [`ReadSections`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IniFiles.TMemIniFile.ReadSections) method.

Comment: It could be like this `^\s*\[(\w+)\]` https://regex101.com/r/CRSaec/1

Comment: I would normally have used the TInifile but in  this particular application it makes calling more consistent with other methods I am using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part in the pattern `[a-z_][0-9]` Matches 2 characters, 1 character being either a-z or _, and the second character being a digit.

You could make 1 character class out of it and repeat it 1+ more times. If you want to match uppercase chars, you can make the pattern case insensitive or add [A-Z] to it.

Then you might also shorten it to `\w`

```
^\s*\[(\w+)\]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CRSaec/1)

**Note** that `\s` also matches a newline. You could also use `\h*` to match 0+ horizontal whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the pattern `'^\[\w+\]$'` to get the sections as:

```
  with TStringList.Create do
    try
      Add('[Compiler]');
      Add('Path=C:\ProgramFiles (x86)\ProtonIDE\PDS');
      Add('Database=C:\Program Files (x86)\ProtonIDE)');
      with TPerlRegEx.Create do
        try
          Options:= [preMultiLine];
          Subject:= Text;
          RegEx:= '^\[\w+\]$';
          while MatchAgain do
            ShowMessage(MatchedText);
            // or ShowMessage(MatchedText.Replace('[', '').Replace(']', '')); if you wish to
        finally
          Free;
        end;
    finally
      Free;
    end;
```

While the simplest way is to use [ReadSections()](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.IniFiles.TMemIniFile.ReadSections) method of `TMemIniFile`

```
  with TMemIniFile.Create('YourIniFile') do
    try
      ReadSections(Memo1.Lines);
    finally
      Free;
    end;
```